# JavaScript: Can't clear array through reassignment when accessing through another reference variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I figured out a work around - need to access the original array variable directly, but I'd like to understand why this happens.

```
var array = ["hello"];

var testObject = {arr: array};

testObject.arr = [];

console.log(array) results in ["hello"] and not [] as expected.
```

However, this method DOES clear array

```
while (testObject.arr.length > 0) {

   testObject.arr.splice(0, 1);

}

console.log(array) results in [] as expected.
```

Can anyone explain what's happening? Thanks!

Oh, also, if I do testObject.arr.push("testing"), it works as expected....

I just don't understand why trying to reassign the array fails.

Comment: `testObject.arr = []` reassigns the reference of `testObject.arr` to a new empty array, while `testObject.arr.splice(0, 1)` mutates the array itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testObject.arr = []` sets the `arr` property of `testObject` - to a brand new array. It doesn't do anything to the value previously assigned to that property. It's mutating `testObject`.

`testObject.arr.splice`, however, mutates the array *at that property*.

Comment: The moment you said "sets to a brand new array" I realized the problem. Ugh. Such a stupid mistake! Thanks!!